# Help me solve this simultaneous linear congruence question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find solutions to: $ x \equiv 4 \mod 7$ and $x \equiv 8 \mod 13$ Here is what I have done so far.

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a solution then $x \equiv 4 \mod 7 \iff x=4+7k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Also $x \equiv 8 \mod 13$ but $x=4+7k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ so $4+7k \equiv 8 \mod 13 \iff 7k \equiv 4 \mod 13$.

I am unsure how to proceed and very stuck. Any help?

Comment: Multiply the congruence by $\, 7^{-1}\equiv 2\,$ to make the coef of $\,k\,$ be $\,\equiv 1\pmod{13}\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

$7k+4=13n+8\iff7~(k-2n)=4-n.~$ But $7=4+3$, so $k-2n=1$ and $n=-3$ form an initial solution, yielding $k=-5$. So $N=n+7a$ and $K=k+13a$ with $a\in$ **Z** form all integer solutions.